# Installation of Microsoft .net framework for linux

Tags: linux, cassandra

I want to install nosql manager on ubuntu for cassandra database. so for that i have installed wine, which helps to run windows applications in ubuntu. so while installing nosql manager, it requires microsoft.net framework also to be installed, so i tried installing but it is not getting installed properly.
what is the best way to install microsoft.net framework latest version 4.5 on ubuntu.

Comment: You *can't*. Only .NET Core is supported on Linux. The process to install .NET Core is [described in the documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-current)

Comment: then nosql manager also won't work right??

Comment: Actually, the question doesn't make sense. Whatever that application is, if it requires 4.5, it's a **Windows** application and can't be installed on Linux at all. If it asks for *.NET Core*, just install the .NET Core runtime it requires. What `nosql manager` are you referring to anyway? If it's a Windows application, why are you trying to install it on *Linux*?

Comment: therefore i am using wine application so that it can install windows applications in ubuntu, nosql manager is the gui tool that i am using for cassandra database

Comment: Or find a *Linux* GUI for Cassandra. After all, Cassandra is a Linux-first database

Comment: yah that is the only option now thank you.

Comment: can you suggest some linux gui for cassandra

Comment: You can find some guis [here](https://anant.github.io/awesome-cassandra/#awesome-cassandra-packages-tools)